# Erro: C# The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, json

Estou com o seguinte erro em C# '*The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context*' na minha aplicação. Segui todos os passos recomendados por diversos sites, como adicionar tais referências e tal, mas o erro continuou.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using DevExpress.XtraRichEdit;

namespace PCMSO
{
  public partial class pcmso : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SalvaTexto(){
        try
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Salvo!. "}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Não foi possível salvar o documento. " + ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: qual é a versão do ASP.net / Framework?

Comment: tem código dentro do try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Segui todos os passos recomendados por diversos sites, como adicionar tais referências e tal`.

Será?

No seu exemplo de código, constam somente os seguintes *namespaces*:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using DevExpress.XtraRichEdit;
```

Nenhum deles possuim um tipo chamado Json. Os três primeiros são de autoria das equipes da Microsoft e são bastante conhecidos. O quarto tem documentação aqui: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.namespace

Você precisa incluir o *namespace* que contém o tipo Json, ou então chamar o tipo pelo nome completo (i.e.: [System.Web.Helpers.Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx), embora pela assinatura, não pareça ser o caso).

---

Existe outra possibilidade aqui, mais provável. Talvez você estivesse pensando no [método Json da classe Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee430920(v=vs.118).aspx). Nesse caso, para o seu código funcionar, a classe na qual você faz sua implementação deve herdar de [System.Web.Mvc.Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.118).aspx). Não é o caso no código que você postou.

Comment: Esqueci de um trecho do código... Fiz a troca de System.Web.UI.Page para Controller e o problema com Json foi resolvido, porém agora aparece 'Mensagem de Erro do Analisador: 'PCMSO.pcmso' não é permitido aqui porque não estende a classe 'System.Web.UI.Page'. quando executo a aplicação.

Comment: @lucaswmolin A classe de controller é uma coisa, a classe de página é outra completamente diferente. Elas são tão diferentes quanto um polvo é diferente de uma bicicleta. E aparentemente você está tentando utilizar coisa de ambas. Infelizmente não tem jeito... Você precisa rever o que está fazendo, pois está misturando coisas incompatíveis.